# html link within a jQuery text string using typed plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the typed library (https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/) and would like to put a link in the string. Simply entering html into the string breaks it.

Heres what i'm trying to work on,

```
$(function(){
    $(".element").typed({
    strings: ["this is where text is and i'd like one of the words to be a link"], 
    typeSpeed: 0
    });
});
```

anything would help. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since the plugin takes one letter a time you won't be able to add in a link, but you could push it at the end:

```
$(function(){
    $(".element").typed({
        strings: ["this is where text is and i'd like one of the words to be a link"], 
    typeSpeed: 0,
        callback: function(){
            addLink($(".element"), "i'd", "http://www.google.com"); // searches for "i'd" and adds link :)
        }
    });
});


function addLink(el, word, link) {
    var rgxp = new RegExp("\\b"+word+"\\b", "gi");
    var repl = '<a href="'+link+'">' + word + '</a>';
    el.html(el.html().replace(rgxp, repl));
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsd4p9d0/)

Answer (score 0):

Jamie, I checked documentation and there's no mentions about custom html integration. You can open an issue on their Github repo for future implementation.

On the other hand, you may consider this [quick implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/carlodurso/6gczpq7b/) I prepared. It still needs some polishing but it's an alternative approach.

```
(function typeIt() {   
    var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (200 - 30)) + 30;
    timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
        char++;
        var type = txt.substring(0, char);
        $el.html(type + '|');
        typeIt();

        if (char == txtLen) {
            $el.html($el.html().slice(0, -1)); // remove the '|'
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }

    }, humanize);
}());
```